# Const Rvalue reference to capture overloads which are not supposed to be compilable

Tags: c++, stl, rvalue-reference, overloading

Scott Meyers in [this talk](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/2188-move-semanticsperfect-forwarding-and-rvalue-references) at 44:15, says `const` Rvalue references are used in c++0x standard library to capture certain overloads which are not supposed to be compilable.

Code snippet to illustrate the above mentioned point would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: [`std::ref`/`std::cref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref), for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One usage that I found useful is to disable temporaries biding to reference members. For example, consider the code below:

```
struct Foo{};

class X
{
    const Foo& _foo;
public:    
    X(const Foo&&) = delete;       // prevents rvalue binding
    X(const Foo& foo): _foo(foo){} // lvalue is OK
};

Foo get_Foo()
{
    return {};
}

const Foo get_const_Foo()
{
    return {};
}

Foo& get_lvalue_Foo()
{
    static Foo foo;
    return foo;
}

int main() 
{
//  X x1{get_Foo()};        // does not compile, use of deleted function
//  X x2{get_const_Foo()};  // does not compile, use of deleted function
    X x3{get_lvalue_Foo()}; // OK
}
```

You definitely want to disable a rvalue being passed to the constructor of `X`, since rvalues **do not bind to const references via constructor parameters**, so you end up with a dangling reference. Why `const Foo&&` and not simply `Foo&&`? Because if you use `X(Foo&&) = delete;`, then if your `get_Foo()` returns `const Foo`  (which is a bad idea, but nevertheless is seen in actual code), it will bind to `X(const Foo&)` instead, and you end up with a dangling reference. However, `X(const Foo&&)` in the code above is a better match for a `const Foo` rvalue, so we obtain the desired effect of not being able to construct an `X` with a rvalue.

You may also ask why not defining `X(Foo&)` instead for the lvalue constructor. Then you won't be able to bind `const` lvalues. So the best approach is to mark `X(const Foo&&) = delete;`. Hope this clarifies it.